# How to design my application to be in sync with external system that I am integrating with using API calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application that integrate with an external system using http API calls, to perform CRUD operations . my current design for this is as follow:-

1. When adding new object:-

   - Send CREATE API Call to external system (object1)
   - If API call is == Success --> CREATE object1 on internal system;
   - If internal system CREATE operation fail --> send DELETE API Call to external sytem.
2. When Deleting exsisting object:-

   - Send DELETE API Call to external system (object1)
   - If API call is == Success  --> DELETE object1 on internal system;
   - If internal system DELETE operation fail --> send CREATE API Call to external.

So in my current design , if any (create or delete ) is committed inside my system then I will be 100% sure that it was confirmed in the external system. But i can not be 100% sure of other scenarios occurred.

So will the above approach works well , and I know it might not cover all the scenarios , especially if the network connection break during the above scenario. But at least it can provide a reliable approach most of the time.

Can anyone advice on how I can improve my approach ?

Comment: Do you have a specific concern?  Otherwise, this is more of a discussion than a question, and it's not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: If internal system DELETE operation fail, why would you want to create a new object on the external system? Your question is quite open, do you have a more specific concern?

Comment: @jdecuyper i will re-create the object on the external system because it was delete through the API call, while it fail internally .